# React-native command unrecognized

Tags: cmd, react-native

I have installed react-native and built some simple application. I ran it and everything was fine. After a while, I could not run anymore my application, because every time I type "react-native start" in cmd, it gets me something like in the picture below. Does anyone have any idea? [image]
EDIT: package json looks like:

```
  {
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.36.0",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-mail": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "16.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "16.0.2",
    "jest-react-native": "16.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: can i see your package.json

Comment: yeah, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

according to me you need to run `npm install` from your root project dir because you might have deleted some file from node_module folder which will be recovered after running the above command.

Comment: did you pass the bug ?

Comment: run with npm start